# Using logical OR (||) in C-Shell

Tags: shell, unix

I have a C-Shell code where I use the following command:

if($#arr == 0 || $arr[1] == "test1") then

It outputs an error message saying "tcsh: arr: Subscript out of range." obviously because the first condition is true. Is it possible to force it to ignore the second condition if  the first condition is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

csh parses the entire line and substitutes variables before evaluating the expression. so in this case, you'd need a nested if because the or condition does not implement short-circuit evaluation with respect to variables.

Comment: I thought so. Thanks for replying!